# How would I configure grub to skip the menu or set a timeout?

Tags: debian, pxe-boot, automated-install, grub2, preseed

I was able to successfully configure PXE and pressed to get an entirely automated install running except for 1 issue:  The GRUB menu pauses indefinitely until the user selects an option.

I've got my grub configured with only a single menu option called Install which kicks off into the installation process.  I want it to skip that menu or I'd like to be able to set a time-out on it so that my datacenter techs don't need to remember to plug a crash cart in to my servers facilitate this process.

Here's my grub.cfg:

```
if loadfont $prefix/font.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=800x600
  set gfxpayload=keep
  insmod efi_gop
  insmod efi_uga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod png
  terminal_output gfxterm
fi

if background_image /isolinux/splash.png; then
  set color_normal=light-gray/black
  set color_highlight=white/black
elif background_image /splash.png; then
  set color_normal=light-gray/black
  set color_highlight=white/black
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi

insmod play
play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1
menuentry 'Install' {
    set background_color=black
    linux    /debian-installer/amd64/linux auto url=tftp://192.168.232.59/preseed.cfg locale=en_US.UTF-8 hostname=install domain=it.corbe.net language=en country=US vga=788 language=en locale=en_US.UTF-8 keymap=us --- quiet
    initrd   /debian-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in the beginning of your grub.cfg:
timeout=0